# How to get the width of an svg:g element

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, width

I am currently working with an `svg` element in JavaScript. And I am new to this.

My question is that I have an `svg` element in which I have multiple `svg:g` elements. And in my `svg:g` elements I have various other svg elements.

```
    <svg>
     <g class="my-class">
      <g class "c1">
         <text style="font-size: 9" x="0" y="-4"> john </text>
         <text style="font-size: 9" x="70" y="-4"> 13 </text>
      </g> 
      <g class="c2">
         <text style="font-size: 9" x="0" y="-4"> john </text>
         <text style="font-size: 9" x="70" y="-4"> 13 </text>
      </g> 
      <g class="c3">
         <text style="font-size: 9" x="0" y="-4"> john </text>
         <text style="font-size: 9" x="70" y="-4"> 13 </text>
      </g> 
    </g>
   </svg>
```

`g` are dynamically appending in my

> g "my_class"

Now I want to set my `svg` width equal to the width of `g.my_class` width.

```
var svgWidth  =   $('.my-class').width()
alert(svgWidth);
```

But its giving me zero. How ever I can see it on my browser in a yellow tool tip box[image]

when I select this line.

Can anyone kindly guide me? Am I doing this right, or how can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Try `.getBoundingClientRect`

```
$('.my-class')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/5DA45/

Comment: Thanks alot @Esailija.But I want to ask one thing that it gives me value of width which is equal to 10 + value of width in tooltip box.Any Idea why is it so

Comment: Thanks @Esailija that worked and Yes I'll prefer getBoundingClientRect() over getBBox(). Reason for that when I need width of "g" I need actual width as per SVG measurements. While getBBox() gives us the width based on Viewbox sizes regardless if the size of the SVG. even if I resize an SVG to 12px ( with viewbox size "0 0 409.215 550.197" ) getBBox() gives me 4.09.215 while I needed original size of the SVG which should be "8.920745849609375" So getBBox is not really useful function to get the size of g in an SVG.

Comment: so for height use $('.my-class')[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;

Answer (score 92):

I'd recommend `getBBox` (which is part of SVG 1.1) over `getBoundingClientRect` (which isn't):

```
$('.my-class')[0].getBBox().width;
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/TAck4/

Comment: *Why* would you recommend it?

Comment: Like it says, because `getBBox` is a required part of the SVG spec, while `getBoundingClientRect` isn't.

Comment: @Yarin - Also, notice that only `getBBox` gets the right coordinates for the top-left corner within the svg (-20,-10): http://jsfiddle.net/QGN6c/20/

Comment: Note that values returned by `getBBox` are in SVG coordinates, whereas `getBoundingClientRect` returns rendered coordinates. In an SVG with `viewBox` instead of width and height, the returned values _could_ be different.

Comment: getBBox gives coords before transformation (translation)