# How to get width of g element?

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I am having some issue with getting width of `<g></g>` element using jQuery. Using `.innerWidth()` or `width()` returns me null. Is it possible to get the `<g></g>` width using jquery?

I am asking this, because of rendering differences between Chrome and IE. In chrome I simply use:

```
var box = svg.node().getBBox();
var width = box.width;
```

But in IE it doesnt work - it returns the widht of 0.

Comment: jQuery doesn't support svgs, behaviour with svgs is hard to predict especially cross browser. Maybe look for an svg specific library.

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702952/how-to-get-the-width-of-an-svgg-element) can help.

Answer (score 0):

Add Id to element Maybe work

```
 <svg viewBox="0 0 95 50"
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <g stroke="green" fill="white" stroke-width="5" id="myGroup">
             <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="15"/>
             <circle cx="40" cy="25" r="15"/>
             <circle cx="55" cy="25" r="15"/>
             <circle cx="70" cy="25" r="15"/>
           </g>
        </svg>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var height =  document.getElementById("myGroup").getBBox().height;
          var width =  document.getElementById("myGroup").getBBox().width;
          alert(" width "+width+" height "+height);
        });
        </script>
```