# Get SVG text element's width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have the following SVG text element:

```
<text data-model-id=​"k10673" x=​"584" y=​"266" fill-opacity=​"1" style=​"font:​ 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;​ " fill=​"#a5d16f">​BU YIL SONU​</text>​
```

It's approximately in the middle of the screen. And I can inspect it as follows:

[image]

I need to get the width of this text.  On chrome debugger, I can see the that the text has a width of 83.941

[image]

However, I cannot get this width from my Javascript page. Any method related to the width returns zero, although it's correctly displayed by Chrome debugger.

I get the element as follows:

```
var x = document.querySelector("#k11489 > g:nth-child(27) > text:nth-child(1)")
```

Then, following Javascript functions all return zero or undefined:

```
x.getComputedTextLength()
x.getBBox().width
x.style.width
```

Also I've tried the following jQuery functions after getting the jQuery object, however, none of them returns the width either:

```
x.width() //Returns the function
x.innerWidth() //Returns null
x.outerWidth() //Returns null
```

**Note:** In order to make sure that x points to the text element, I check them through the console. Following are the snapshots of Javascript and jQuery objects:

[image]

[image]

How can I get this object's width in by Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: Are you waiting until the DOM is ready before attempting to access the elements?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I am trying these from Chrome's developer console, minutes after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Do you know if `x` points to the text element?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes, I edited the question and added snapshots of x pointing to the text element.

Comment: OK. Can we see the declaration of the SVG element itself? When I test with `getComputedTextLength` or `getBBox`, I can get the width of the text element, but I am not sure that it is declared in the same context as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if it works on textelements, but for me, the

`document.querySelector('.whatever').getBoundingClientRect().width;`

works, and respects current scaling of the svg. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702952/how-to-get-the-width-of-an-svgg-element) - adapting the accepted answers fiddle to target a text node, works for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can use getBBox() (which is part of SVG 1.1) to get the width of an svg element as below.

```
$("your_jquery_selector")[0].getBBox().width.
```

If it's valid selector then use

```
$("#k11489 > g:nth-child(27) > text:nth-child(1)")[0].getBBox().width
```

Comment: The OP states in the question that they tried this and it returns 0.

Comment: I tested both jquery function and javscript function and both worked for one of my local tests. Please see this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/q2jhjggwiv691bi/svg.png?dl=0.  As he has applied this function to the javascript, the problem could be with the dom selector. If the particular element does not exist, then eventually he will get a undefined for the with. First thing is he has to make sure, the selector is correct

Comment: All that proves is that the OP is doing something different. The element does exist as he shows the results of the selection in the screenshots in the question.

Comment: `.getBBox().width` shows me the original width of the element, not the current one (svg might be shown in different size...)...